# Getting 301 Error when making HTTP GET Requests using C++ sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, http, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am trying to make GET requests from a C++ program and every time I get a 301 Moved Permanently error. I am using an API that uses sockets and cannot seem to figure out why this error always comes up.

Here is the request that is getting made:

```
GET https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/EOD/AAPL.csv?sort_order=asc&auth_token=YZffVEztoepdzHNAMexz HTTP/1.1
Host: www.quandl.com
Connection: close
```

And here is the response to the request:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Sun, 12 Nov 2017 03:58:41 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 182
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d51b8e22f5239ed65b480d8ec37cad8251510459121; expires=Mon, 12-Nov-18 03:58:41 GMT; path=/; domain=.quandl.com; HttpOnly
Location: https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/EOD/AAPL.csv?sort_order=asc&auth_token=YZffVEztoepdzHNAMexz
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 3bc6930581840ed9-EWR

<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>openresty</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I think it may have to do with the Http-only part in the Set-cookie but am not 100% sure about that and don't know how to get rid of it. I think the url in the response after location is where the page has "moved to", however it is the exact same one as the one I am requesting so I don't understand why I am getting the error.

Comment: Maybe you should learn more about [the HyperText Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure that's going to be a huge help for me especially since it will take a lot of time. Also, the main reason I am using an API is so I don't have to learn sockets and HTTP and construct them myself. Plus, I think even if I did know more this issue would still confuse me as I am getting a Moved Permanently error and the url I am being told the page moved to is the same as the url I am sending the request to.

Comment: If you don't know how the underlying layers work, or how the protocol you use work, then you practically become unable to solve *simple* problems like this. If you knew about HTTP and what 301 means, you would be able to easily extract the data you need from the response and do what is needed. And no, it has nothing to do with cookies.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "*And no, it has nothing to do with cookies.*" - not necessarily. The URL in question is redirecting back to itself. The only reason for an HTTP server to ever do that is when the request is missing data that the server wants, like cookies. In this case, there is no cookie in the request, but there is a cookie in the redirect, so the server likely requires that cookie and won't accept a request without it. A redirect is a good way to force a *compliant* client to send it. The OP's client is clearly not compliant since it doesn't understand how to react to an HTTP redirect

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'll admit I didn't check the URLs. However, a redirection response *by itself* doesn't really have anything to do with cookies.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I see you say this is a "simple" problem and was wondering if you had a simple fix. While I should learn more about HTTP right now I am really in search of a relatively quick solution as my goal in this project is not to learn HTTP but using it to retrieve data would be very useful.

Comment: The "simple" solution is to extract the URL from the `Location` header and retry the request using that URL. However in the light of the comment by @RemyLebeau, cookies are involved and you probably need to provide that cookie with your request.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The URL in the location is exactly the same one as the original one I sent, that is why I was so confused with the error, so I doubt that would change anything. Since the cookie expires after 1 day basically I cannot get a cookie and hard code it in, do you know if it is possible to get a cookie using sockets to send with the original request?

Comment: You already have the cookie, it's in the response header you got. You just need to extract it and provide it as a header in the second request you make.

Comment: I will do that, I was just wondering if there was a way to get the cookie first as opposed to making a bad request intentionally, have to parse it to get the cookie, then make a second request with it, since that seems like better practice. But I will try out extracting it then using it and hopefully that works

Comment: It's not really a "bad request", this is simply how much of the web works these days. If you clear your browser of cookies and look at the requests sent and responses received, you will see quite a lot of these redirections. Even with cookies set you will see quite a lot of redirections.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, I'm not sure the cookies solution is the answer! I tried sending a request with the cookie returned and I get the exact same error.

Answer (score 1):

```
GET https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/EOD/AAPL.csv?sort_order=asc&auth_token=YZffVEztoepdzHNAMexz HTTP/1.1
Host: www.quandl.com
Connection: close
```

That's not a valid request for a `https://` resource. Instead you have to create a TLS connection to the server (instead of only a TCP connection) and send the request with path-only instead of full-URL:

```
GET /api/v3/datasets/EOD/AAPL.csv?sort_order=asc&auth_token=YZffVEztoepdzHNAMexz HTTP/1.1
Host: www.quandl.com
Connection: close
```

Comment: The original would be a valid request if sending it through an HTTP proxy

Comment: @RemyLebeau: This would be the case for `http://` only. But this is a `https://` request which means that it would use the CONNECT method to build a tunnel through the proxy  and then establish a TLS connection inside this tunnel and finally send the HTTP request with path only instead of a `https://` URL. With HTTPS the TLS connection is  end-to-end between client and server even when using a HTTP proxy. It does not get changed to a plain connection between client and proxy and a TLS connection between  proxy and server.

Comment: If this is the case I guess this function is causing the issue, setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &on, sizeof(on));. I don't think there is a IPPROTO_TLS option, but I think there is an SSL option so would using SSL be a possible solution?

Comment: @Kyle: TLS is way more complex then TCP and thus creating a TLS connection is not as simple as just setting a socket option. How to do it is out of scope of this question but information about it can be widely found on the internet. The exact details depend on your programming language and operating system.

Answer (score 0):

301 isn't an error, it means the resource has changed URL's.

When you get this valid response code you can issue another request to the Location URL specified in the response.

Be careful to limit the number of times you follow a redirect because you could wind up with an infinite loop.  A lot of HTTP client libraries have an option to handle this automatically.

Comment: But the redirection url is exactly the same as the original url, so I am not sure sending another request will change anything.

Comment: Are you using Poco or what?  Try it with curl -L and see if that works.  If curl doesn't work, the server may be misconfigured.